# Syntax Error - Navigating Pages

Tags: java, android, syntax, navigation, syntax-error

I appear to be getting syntax error when I try to build my application. I am trying to navigate from one page to another but appear to be getting 6 syntax errors. Could I please have some assistance as to where I am going wrong!

```
package com.techblogon.loginexample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle setInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(setInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnhealth);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent activityChangeIntent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, Tips.class);



                MainMenu.this.startActivity(activityChangeIntent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: which lines are the problematic?

Comment: Can you provide your logcat?